# Extract sub-string between 2 apexes from one column of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
hometown
0   b'Rome, Italy'
1   b'Kadrina'
2   b'Hasselt'
3   b'Recife, Brazil'
4   unknown
...
35677318    unknown
35677319    unknown
```

I would like to extract only the text between the apexes (e.g. *b'Rome, Italy'* --> *Rome, Italy*), after that, I would like to split the text into two different columns, like this:

```
hometown     country
0   Rome     Italy
1   Kadrina  unknown
2   Hasselt  unknown
3   Recife   Brazil
4   unknown  unknown
...
35677318    unknown  unknown
35677319    unknown  unknown
```

Comment: 1) Your data is binary string. You may need `decode`. 2) Then `str.split(', ', expand=True)`.

Comment: Could you give me a practical example?